# Reduce redudant coding Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this function inside a class

```
def readInput(self, inFile):
    with open(inFile, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            if (line.split()[0] == "Ks"):
                nextLine = next(file)
                self.Ks = nextLine.split()[0]
                self.thetaS = nextLine.split()[1]
                self.thetaR = nextLine.split()[2]
                self.alpha = nextLine.split()[3]
                self.lamb = nextLine.split()[4]
                self.n = nextLine.split()[5]
```

It basically search for a pattern (`"Ks"`) inside an input file (`inFile`) to store variable values from the next line of `inFile` inside instance variables.

There is a lot of repetition in the code and I think it's possible to write that in a clever (and shorter) way.

Any ideas?

The input file looks like this:

```
### Soil hydraulic properties. Units: m, d
Ks      ThetaS  ThetaR  alpha   lambda  n
0.128   0.01    0.42    0.84    -1.497  1.441
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using tuple unpacking:

```
self.Ks, self.thetaS, self.thetaR, self.alpha, self.lamb, self.n = nextLine.split()
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use the standard [CSV package](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html).

```
import csv

with open('testdata.csv', newline='') as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    next(csvreader)  # omit the comment at start of file
    header = next(csvreader)
    for row in csvreader:
        print(', '.join(row))
```